# Applescript: Wait for an action/event to complete

Tags: download, applescript, delay, wait

I am writing a script to download Free/non-Free applications from iTunes Store.
For each download , it is taking 5 to 10 seconds.

For example:

repeat 1000 times

download_app()

end repeat

on download_app()

download stuff ....

delay 10

end download_app

For downloading one application 1000 times, it is taking big amount of time and I want to optimize this timing. Instead of using delay 10, is there any other way to do this ?

Is there an way to get downloading status / busy status of iTunes?

Please suggest.

Advanced Thanks

Rahman

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a specific solution, however the following code may provide a useful example:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "Safari"
        repeat
            if (accessibility description of (get properties of button 1 of text field 1 of splitter group 1 of group 2 of tool bar 1 of window 1)) does not contain "stop" then exit repeat
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

This code pauses a script until a webpage has finished loading. It does so by entering an infinite loop and breaking out of the loop upon reaching a condition.

The condition appears rather complex, but it really checks something simple. At the right side of the Safari URL field there's a stop/reload button. While the page is loading, it shows a stop icon. Once the page stops loading, it shows a reload icon. Hence, when we no longer see the stop icon, the page must have finished loading.

Most of the code rather cryptically navigates the GUI to identify the button described. The term `accessibility description` is used to identify the current state of the button. The accessibility description is what is spoken aloud to handicapped (e.g. visually impaired) individuals who are running Mac OS X under accessibility mode. Naturally, while the page is loading the button is described as "stop."

If some interactive aspect of the iTunes GUI changes (most likely a button) when a download completes, you can detect its change of state in a similar fashion and use that as a cue to continue the script.

Hope that helps. ([My example implementation of the code.](https://gist.github.com/armanbilge/6290305) I have found it to be ridiculously precise—the script continues instantaneously after the page finishes loading.)

*Disclosure: Not my original code—I found it somewhere on the internet.*